# Unable to pass dropdown value to datatable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have drop down list,im trying to pass a value to datatable function ,value is passing to the function but jquery data table is not initialising. but getting error saying -

> "DataTables warning: table id=example1 - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error

html

```
<select name="navyOp" onchange="getApi(this.value);">
        <option selected="selected">Select a tank</option>
        <option value="32F"> top</option>
        <option value="330">bottom</option>
      </select>
```

javascript

```
getApi("032F");
function getApi(deviceid) {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var dataSet = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);//deserialization
            //start jquery code
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example1').DataTable({
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [



                        { data: "port", title: "port" },
                        { data: "rssi", title: "rssi" }
                    ]

                });
            });

            //end jquery code
        }

    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "BASIC avv==");
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [



                        { data: "port", title: "port" },
                        { data: "rssi", title: "rssi" }
                    ]

                });  table..draw();`

Comment: Move your table initialization from `$(document).read` and assign table initialization into variable. Use `draw()` method in `onreadystatechange` event.Take reference of above comment.